# Lineinfile sometimes doesn't replace lines

Tags: ansible

I have nginx upstream with multiple backends. I use `pre_tasks` in playbook for disabling backends in the upstream config during deployment:

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: '{{ list_hosts }}'
  serial: 4

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Disable hosts in nginx upstream
    replace:
      path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf
      regexp: '^        server {{ LAN }}:'
      line: '        #server {{ LAN }}:5001;'
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{groups['nginx_api']}}"
...
```

It works, but not always correct. Sometimes it disables not all 4 hosts (serial: 4)
I think it happens because it tries to replace 4 lines at the same time.

Is it possible to do each iteration one by one and keep `serial: 4`?

**Update:**

Sorry, my last test was with `replace`

To regexp added `^` (thanks @bviktor)

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: '{{ list_hosts }}'
  serial: 4

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Disable server in nginx upstream
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf
      regexp: '^        server {{ LAN }}:5001;'
      line: '        #server {{ LAN }}:5001;'
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{groups['nginx_api']}}"
```

In inventory

```
[nginx_api]
api1 ansible_host=x.x.y.1   LAN=10.x.y.1
api2 ansible_host=x.x.y.2   LAN=10.x.y.2
api3 ansible_host=x.x.y.3   LAN=10.x.y.3
api4 ansible_host=x.x.y.4   LAN=10.x.y.4
[app]
app1 ansible_host=x.x.x.1   LAN=10.x.x.1
app2 ansible_host=x.x.x.2   LAN=10.x.x.2
app3 ansible_host=x.x.x.3   LAN=10.x.x.3
app4 ansible_host=x.x.x.4   LAN=10.x.x.4
app5 ansible_host=x.x.x.5   LAN=10.x.x.5
...
```

Upstream conf before run:

```
upstream app {
least_conn;
        server 10.x.x.1:5001;
        server 10.x.x.2:5001;
        server 10.x.x.3:5001;
        server 10.x.x.4:5001;
        server 10.x.x.5:5001;
    ...

}
```

Upstream conf after run:

```
upstream app {
least_conn;
        server 10.x.x.1:5001;
        #server 10.x.x.2:5001;
        server 10.x.x.3:5001;
        server 10.x.x.4:5001;
        server 10.x.x.5:5001;
    ...

}
```

Expected result:

```
upstream app {
least_conn;
        #server 10.x.x.1:5001;
        #server 10.x.x.2:5001;
        #server 10.x.x.3:5001;
        #server 10.x.x.4:5001;
        server 10.x.x.5:5001;
    ...

}
```

Just when I run the playbook several times it disables 4 needed hosts in upstream

Comment: We'd have to see the files to give you any meaningful advice...

Comment: Also, you use "replace", not "lineinfile", as the title suggests.

Comment: @bviktor I've updated question

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where does the group *nginx_api* come from? What is the example of *list_hosts*? What is the origin of *upstream.conf*? And what is the expected result? ...

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and asked to close.

Comment: @VladimirBotka  Thanks for the comment. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You give us very little to work with, but in general, it's not a very good practice to replace a pattern with something that is a superset of such pattern. Why? Because on consecutive runs, it will match over and over, since it includes the original pattern. So `server {{ LAN }}` becomes `#server {{ LAN }}`, then `##server {{ LAN }}`, then `###server {{ LAN }}`, and so on. Use `^` or some other pattern to indicate the preceding pattern. For example, if you use something like

```
regexp: '^server {{ LAN }}:'
```

It will only match if the line starts with `server`, i.e. it doesn't have any `#` preceding it, and therefore it won't put any more `#` characters before it upon consecutive runs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I've updated my question

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use a [throttle](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle)

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: '{{ list_hosts }}'
  serial: 4

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Disable server in nginx upstream
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf
      regexp: '^        server {{ LAN }}:5001;'
      line: '        #server {{ LAN }}:5001;'
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    throttle: 1
    with_items: "{{groups['nginx_api']}}"
```